# What is the Default content in /private/etc/paths?

Tags: macos, path

I have edited `/private/etc/paths` to allow access for `Homebrew`:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

I want to restore this file to the system Defaults. What are the default lines and default order?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default content of */etc/paths* until Mavericks (10.9) is:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

The default content of */etc/paths* since Yosemite (10.10) is:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Answer (score 2):

In OS X 10.11 ( El Capitan ) the order and content of /etc/paths is:

```
 /usr/local/bin
 /usr/bin
 /bin
 /usr/sbin
 /sbin
```

Additionally, having installed Xquartz via MacPorts, I note the addition of one entry in /etc/paths.d/ called 40-XQuartz, which contains the following:

```
 /opt/X11/bin
```

As I recall, convention has it that /etc/paths is evaluated first, with any entries in /etc/paths.d being appended.  Some optional / additional package managers make modifications to either the .profile or .bashrc at the root level of your user's home directory.

Are you having problems with the PATH variable related to optional / additional package managers like home-brew?

Warm Regards,

F.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The reason I wanted to revert to default is because I decided to export the path in `.bash_profile` instead via: `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`. I too have XQuartz installed, but I don't have `/opt/X11/bin` in `/private/etc/paths` nor `.bash_profile`. When running `which xquartz` it says `/opt/X11/bin/xquartz`. So I'm assuming that is appended from `etc/paths.d` automatically like you said.

Answer (score 1):

Chiming for an update, since I have my doubts: as of 13.4 `/etc/paths` is

```
/usr/local/bin
/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

as well as a couple entries in `/etc/paths.d/`:

```
10-cryptex      40-XQuartz      at.obdev.littlesnitch
100-rvictl      Wireshark       mono-commands
```

I believe some of these aren't pristine, namely the non-numbered ones.

I was trying to see if that system was usable to insert Homebrew's paths globally, but as it turns out `/usr/sbin/path_helper` generates `PATH` by reading `/etc/paths` then files in `/etc/paths.d` in order, so you have no way of inserting something in front.